# fromjson fails to parse scientific notation - Android

Tags: android, parsing, gson, scientific-notation, fromjson

When I use `Gson().fromJson(objJsonStr, MyClass::class.java)` and the string has a long number in scientific notation like 5.83949726077129E9, it fails to handle it and gives exception. How can I make it handle scientific notations as well, without changing the incoming string?

This is the exception I get:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected a long but was 1.583949726077129E9 at line 1 column 194 path $timestamp
```

.

```
class MyClass : Serializable {
    var timestamp: Long? = null
}
```

Json looks like:

```
{"timestamp":1.224746379E9}
```

But check this online site treats it as Long integer

[image]

Comment: What exception? How *exactly* are you using it? Numbers in scientific notation are not `long`/`Long`, they're floating point.

Comment: @DaveNewton Check the edits. So u suggest that I change the "long" variable to double?.

Comment: Would have been quicker to just try it--but that would be my initial suggestion, yes; you're not getting a `Long` back.

Comment: Could you show me objJsonStr value?

Comment: @Genesis Added Json example